# facebook graph api to fetch videos

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

How get the videos from a facebook page with PHP and Graph API? Right now I am using FQL to get videos:

```
$fql = "SELECT vid, owner, title, description, thumbnail_link, embed_html, updated_time, created_time FROM video WHERE owner = PAGE_ID";

$response = $facebook->api(array(
'method' => 'fql.query',
'query' =>$fql,
));
```

I would also like to get the likes, like counts and comments for the videos. Is it also possible to use condition in Graph API? Like "Where description = 'myvideo'"... something like this. If anyone know, please show me in detail with example.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use `WHERE` on indexed fields (the ones that are marked with a star in the docs). The other stats are not available for the video itself, but to the post the videos appears in. So you need to know where the video has been used and query for this post/status/comment/... id.